# Program not functionning

Tags: javascript, onclick, innerhtml

I'm still new in JavaScript. I am trying to make a program that contains 2 buttons and once a button is clicked, it creates a random number.

The problem is that when I'm trying to compare them, it is not showing which one is bigger. First I thought the problem is that the variables aren't global but it didn't change anything.

Can someone help me find the problem please?

Here is the **JavaScript** code:

```js
var par1 = document.getElementById("para1");
var par2 = document.getElementById("para2");
var winner = document.getElementById("win");
 
function button1() {
    num1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    par1.innerHTML = num1;
}
 
function button2() {
    num2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 7);
    par2.innerHTML = num2;
}
if (num1 > num2) {
    winner.innerHTML = "the winner is player 1";
} else {
    winner.innerHTML = "the winner is player 2";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>dicestimulator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dicestimulator.css">
</head>
 
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div>
            <h1>Player1</h1>
            <button type="button" name="button1" onclick="button1()" id="but1">roll 
    dice</button>
            <p id="para1">Click the button to see what you get</p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1>Player2</h1>
            <button type="button" name="button2" id="but2" onclick="button2()">roll 
     dice</button>
            <p id="para2">Click the button to see what you get</p>
        </div>
        <p id="win">let's see who wins!!!</p>
        <script src="dicestimulator.js"></script>
    </div>
</body>
 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(num1>num2){
winner.innerHTML="the winner is player 1";
}else{
winner.innerHTML="the winner is player 2";
}
```

You are not calling the above block no where in your HTML code.

My solution for you make a third button that calls the function getwinner

```
function getWinner() {
if(par1.val>par2.val){
winner.innerHTML="the winner is player 1";
} else{
winner.innerHTML="the winner is player 2";
}
}
```

Please note that you cannot call local variables created in functions outside those functions. num1 and num2 cease to exist after the scope of the function that created them.

Answer (score 1):

The section of code:

> ```
> if(num1>num2){
> winner.innerHTML="the winner is player 1";
> }else{
> winner.innerHTML="the winner is player 2";
> }
> ```

… is **not inside a function**.

It runs when the script is initially loaded.

Later on, you call the `button1` and `button2` functions. These change the values of `num1`.

You never compare the values **again**.

If you want to compare them when the `button1` and `button2` functions run, then the code needs to be called when those functions are.